# Popup doesn't go away after showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an image gallery with bootstrap, but after the bigger image shows up, it doesn't go away after cliking outside the image. I am using asp.net mvc 5

I have this:

css/html:

```
<div id="tabs-2">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4 img-thumbnail">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://lorempixel.com/800/600/food/1" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4 img-thumbnail">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://lorempixel.com/800/600/food/2" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4 img-thumbnail">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://lorempixel.com/800/600/food/3" alt="" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-body"></div>
            </div>
            <!-- /.modal-content -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal -->
</div>
```

and this is the jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $myModal = $('#myModal');

            $('.row img.img-responsive').on('click', function () { // <-- notice the selector change
                var $this = $(this),
                    src = $this.attr('src'),
                    html = '<img src="' + src + '" class="img-responsive" />';

                updateModalBody($myModal, html);

                $myModal.modal();
            });

            $myModal.on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
                updateModalBody($myModal, '');
            });

            function updateModalBody($modal, html) {
                $modal.find('.modal-body').html(html);
            }
        })
```

And I dont get any errors in the browser.

Thank you

[image]

[image]

if I am using this:

```
function updateModalBody($modal, html) {
                $modal.find('.modal-body').html(html);
                $modal.modal('hide');
            }
```

the the image dissapear if you click on a other image, so not outside the images.

ok,

this is now my javascript:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            $myModal = $('#myModal');

            $('.row img.img-responsive').on('click', function () { // <-- notice the selector change
                var $this = $(this),
                    src = $this.attr('src'),
                    html = '<img src="' + src + '" class="img-responsive" />';


                updateModalBody($myModal, html);

                $myModal.modal();
            });

            $myModal.on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {



                updateModalBody($myModal, '');
            });

            function updateModalBody($modal, html) {
                $modal.find('.modal-body').html(html);
                $modal.modal('hide');
            }

        })


        $(document).ready(function()  {
            $('#myModal').on('shown', function () {
                $('#myModal').modal('hide');
            })
        });
```

and this is the css/html:

```
<div class="modal hide fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">

                    <div class="modal-dialog">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-body"></div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.modal-content -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.modal-dialog -->

            </div>
```

but the close(x) button doesnt work.

Comment: It works fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/mdawood1991/5hv5t7mv/

Comment: can you give your jsfiddle

Comment: Yes, I know of jsfiddle it works, I see that, but by me the picture doesnt go away. and I dont see any errors. SO maybe there is a forced way , that the image goes away, after clicking outside the image. I have added a picture. But also if I click on the image, the background doesnt change gey, and in Fiddle the background changed to grey

Comment: I also put a image for showing there are no errors showing

Comment: But do you need the library: bootstrap-modal.js?

Comment: IF you are using the min version it contains the bootstrap-modal. So you don't need it. Make sure you are only referencing jQuery and Bootstrap once.

Comment: I just included this:   <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />   
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script> but it just sticks on the screen, so the modal shows up, but sticks

Comment: But how can I make an x on the modal, that the if you click on the x the modal dissapears. Maybe that helps

Comment: First example has a 'x' http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

Comment: oke, Iv updated my post, with the close button

Comment: @Dawood, can you have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30192146/slide-show-with-bootstrap?noredirect=1#comment48489906_30192146. thank you