# slide show with bootstrap

Tags: jquery, css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I try to make a slide show with bootstrap, so that you slide through the images. But the images are not showing. Only the next and previous buttons are showing. I am using asp.net mvc5

this is the jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $myModal = $('#myModal');

            $('.row img.img-responsive').on('click', function () { // <-- notice the selector change
                var $this = $(this),
                    src = $this.attr('src'),
                    html = '<img src="' + src + '" class="img-responsive" />';

                //Start 
                var index = $(this).parent('.row img.img-responsive').index();
                var html = '';
                html += html;
                html += '<div style="height:25px;clear:both;display:block;">';
                html += '<a class="controls next" href="' + (index + 2) + '">next &raquo;</a>';
                html += '<a class="controls previous" href="' + (index) + '">&laquo; prev</a>';
                html += '</div>';
                //End 


                updateModalBody($myModal, html);
                $myModal.modal();
            });

            $myModal.on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {

                updateModalBody($myModal, '');
            });

            function updateModalBody($modal, html) {
                $modal.find('.modal-body').html(html);
                $modal.modal('hide');
            }

        })

        $(document).on('click', 'a.controls', function () {
            //this is where we add our logic
            var index = $(this).attr('href');
            var src = $('ul.row li:nth-child(' + index + ') img').attr('src');

            $('.modal-body img').attr('src', src);

            var newPrevIndex = parseInt(index) - 1;
            var newNextIndex = parseInt(newPrevIndex) + 2;

            if ($(this).hasClass('previous')) {
                $(this).attr('href', newPrevIndex);
                $('a.next').attr('href', newNextIndex);
            } else {
                $(this).attr('href', newNextIndex);
                $('a.previous').attr('href', newPrevIndex);
            }

            var total = $('ul.row li').length + 1;
            //hide next button
            if (total === newNextIndex) {
                $('a.next').hide();
            } else {
                $('a.next').show()
            }
            //hide previous button
            if (newPrevIndex === 0) {
                $('a.previous').hide();
            } else {
                $('a.previous').show()
            }


            return false;
        });
```

and this the css/html:

```
<div id="tabs-2">
    <div class="row">
        @foreach (var item in Model.LolaBikePhotos)
        {

            @model  ContosoUniversity.Models.UserProfile
            @*<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb">*@
            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4 img-thumbnail">
                @*<a class="thumbnail">*@
                <img class="img-responsive" src="/Images/profile/@item.ImagePath" alt="" />
            </div>

            <div class="modal hide fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">

                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-body"></div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.modal-content -->
                </div>
                <!-- /.modal-dialog -->

            </div>
    <!-- /.modal -->
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

Thank you

I have to edit this:

```
html += html;
```

But I dont know how to change that.

This is how you will see it:[image]

Comment: There is something wrong with your code, I am not an ASP developer but please look at Bootstrap Carousel documentation and follow their steps to create a working example: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel

Comment: If you're still having trouble, please provide your *generated* HTML--the markup that results after your asp.net code is parsed.

Comment: Have you tried this: src="@Url.Content(string.Format("~/Images/Profile/{0}", item.ImagePath))"?

Comment: The problem of image not showing is you are not providing the correct path to image

Comment: Hi Dawood, I mean the images are showing, but if you click on the image the slider with the images is not vissible, I will add a picture. The images in the slider are not vissible. I have updated the post

Comment: What do you mean the images in the slider are not visible? Do you mean you want those 8 images to be in a Carousel ?

Comment: yes, with previous and next, but is this correct?  html += html;

Comment: With my previous post, that you will get a bigger image if you click on the thumbnail, but now that you can slide through the 8 pictures, with nex and previous

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make this simple

If you look at the HTML from 
http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel

Copy the first one and add some `Razor`, this should generate a Carousel for you.

```
@model List<YOUR_MODEL_NAME>
    @{var j = 0;}
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
     @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
     {
       <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="@i"></li>
      }
  </ol>

<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">

 @foreach (var item in Model)
  {
   <div class="item @(j == 0 ? "active" : "")">
       <img src="@(string.Format("/Images/profile/{0}", item.ImagePath))" />
   </div>
  @(j = 1)
  }

</div>

<a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
<span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
</a>
<a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
<span class="sr-only">Next</span>
</a>
</div>
```

**EDIT**

Following is an Example of a Thumbnails, when the thumbnails are clicked it will open a modal-dialog with a carousel in it.

I have created a JSFiddle of your scenario:
http://jsfiddle.net/u7hxy3zc/1/

You should use the following code as an example and use in your View, Renaming all models and parameters.

*Note: The following code has not been compiled May have syntax errors*

```
// DISPLAY THUMBNAILS
<div class="col-md-2">
@for(int i =0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
  {
    <img src="@Model[i].ImageUrl" data-id="@i" data-action="image" />
  }        
</div>



.......... REMOVE HTML TO MAKE EXAMPLE CLEAR
... MODAL DIALOG START.................


<div class="modal-body">

...........CAROUSEL START............


<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
@for(var i = 0 ; i< Model.Count(); i++)
{
<li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="@i"></li>
}
</ol>

<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">

@for(var i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
{
<div class="item" data-image-id="@i">

  // DISPLAY i for Testing      
    @i     

   <img src="@Model[i].ImageUrl"  />
}
</div>

........... REMOVED REST OF CAROUSEL......(NEXT / PREV BUTTONS).........

.............CAROUSEL END...................
```

Then add this jQuery at the end to trigger the click event:

```
$('body').on('click', '*[data-action="image"]', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    var img = $(this);
    var currentId = img.data('id');
    $('#myModal').modal();
    var currentSlide = "*[data-slide-to='" + currentId + "']";
    var currentImagSlide = "*[data-image-id='" + currentId + "']";

    console.log(currentSlide);

    $("*[data-slide-to]").removeClass("active");
    $(".item").removeClass("active");

    var item = $('.carousel-indicators').find(currentSlide);
    var imgItem = $('.carousel-inner').find(currentImagSlide);
    console.log(item);
    item.addClass("active");
    imgItem.addClass("active");
});
```

Comment: Consider parameterizing those `id` attributes so this can be reused multiple times within any given page.

Comment: @DaWood, thank you for your answare. But it has to be a photo gallery, but that you can slide between the big images with next and previous. so the thumbnails has to been shown anyway, like I have it now, but if you click on a image, then you can slide between the images, and not that you have to click on each thumbnail seperated if you want to see the bigger format of it. Sorry for my misunderstanding. Like this: https://demos.devexpress.com/MVCxImageAndDataNavigationDemos/ImageSlider/PhotoGallery

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="..." alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        ...
      </div>
    </div>
    ...
  </div>

  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Definitely look into bootstrap carousel